# android getSubscriptions given empty array for my ids but work with this "android.test.purchased'" test id react-native-iap

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, react-native-in-app-utils

**Version of react-native-iap**

4.3.0

**Version of react-native**

0.63.3

**Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)**

Android

**Expected behavior**

should give an array of my subscription that I added on my google console.

**Actual behavior**

gives an empty array

**Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)**

"android.test.purchased" working both on the emulator and real device but my ids are not working empty array always

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

[image]

Please help me out with this it's working fine for iOS. Even I put my app on alpha and testing reviews are also done.

**Q2. One more question I need to know is it mandatory to verify the receipts from the backend what if I leave this step?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get my subscription in an array finally it's not empty. Ok so to get the subscription/products you must have to release your app on **Open Testing / Closed Testing / Internal Testing**. once you are able to see your app on the play store as a beta available for testing then you are able to get the subscription or products in the array. Hope this will be helpful for anyone who faces this issue afterwards Cheers!

Comment: It still returns an empty array, My app is available for closed testing in the play store.

Comment: Same.  Releasing did not help.